# How to test Web Service I've created?

Tags: java, web-services

How am I going to test the Web Service that I've created?

For example, I've created and addition method and would like to test, how do I call the method on `.HTML` file?

Comment: What kind of Web Service? SOAP? REST? What libraries do you use?

Comment: Isn't it a topic of http://sqa.stackexchange.com? Which code problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: How can I check? I'm truly sorry as I'm just getting started and got no help from anyone.

Comment: Please show us some part of server code. Which API is used ?

Answer (score 0):

if your webservice is a restful one, deploy it on your application server and then browse to the path, on which the webservice will listen, remember you had to define this in the Class.

If it is a SOAP based one, generate the webservice client from the wsdl page and start the client and query your webservice.

EDIT:

Did you define some xml schema file(s) or only wrote a class with some Annotation like @PATH or @Produces("application/json") for example?

Comment: Absolutely no xml schema been written. What I've done now is just create a method addition which add 2 numbers together.

Comment: Oh, this sounds just like a little RMI Service. [link](http://www.professional-webworkx.de/java-rmi-little-starting-example/) Here is an example. You need to create a server class which provides a method for add 2 numbers and registers in the naming directory when he will be started, a client, who does a naming lookup and gets a proxy object of the server, which will delegate all operations directly to the server. you followed a online tutorial? if yes, pls post the link

Comment: Ah, ok. Last time i create a WebService i first created a Dynamic Web Project, a ServiceClass, which was annotated with "@WebService" and some Service Methods, annotated with "@WebMethod".. then i right clicked on the WebProject and said i want to create a new WebService from scratch, the dialog wanted to now which serviceclass i want to use and suggests you all your "@WebService "annotated classes. then click finish and start your applicationserver and there you can use localhost:8080/ProjectName/Servicename?wsdl for watching the wsdl in your browser. Copy the link and create ws client

Comment: Thank you for the guidance ! Really appreciate it since I'm just getting started and got no guidance. Tried with Google but doesn't give much help (or I'm bad at Googling things). Thank you once again !